# Adding a name to a list in alphabetical order?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Suppose I have a linked list of names. Each node is placed in alphabetical order. How can I properly loop through and insert the name at the correct position? We are assuming that it is case insensitive.

```
def add(self, name):
    if self._size == 0:
        self.add_first(name)
        self._size += 1
    elif self._size >= 1:
        cur = self._head
        while name.upper() > cur.upper() or cur.get_next is not None:
```

and this is where I am stuck

A node is coded as the following

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, element, next_node=None):
        self._element = element
        self._next = next_node

    def set_next(self, next_node):
        self._next = next_node

    def set_element(self, element):
        self._element = element

    def get_next(self):
        return self._next

    def get_element(self):
        return self._element
```

Comment: This question is not specific to Python - it is more a question about how to work with a sorted linked list. I recommend adding a `data-structures` and/or `linked-list` tag if you do not want to look for related resources online.

Comment: Can you provide the whole class definition so we understand the whole picture. For example, the variable `contact`, `get_next`......

Answer (score 0):

Below is a general iterative implementation.  You'll have to adapt it to your linked list class.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, _next):
        self.val = val
        self.next = _next 
    def add(self, name):
        up = name.upper()
        if up < self.val.upper():
            return Node(name, self)  
            # We could also change self.val to update the head 
            # without worrying about returning values:
            # self.val, self.next = name, Node(self.val, self.next)
        curr = self
        while True:    
            if not curr.next:
                curr.next = Node(name, None)
                break
            else:
                if curr.val.upper() < up < curr.next.val.upper():
                    curr.next = Node(name, curr.next)
                    break
                else:
                    curr = curr.next
        return self
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node({0.val}, {0.next!r})".format(self)

head = Node("Adam", None)
head = head.add("Aardvark")
head = head.add("Bob")
print(head)
# Node(Aardvark, Node(Adam, Node(Bob, None)))
```

Comment: Thank you but I trying to figure it out while avoiding recursive implementation